# FirebaseAuthListener presenta error al momento de implementar

Tags: android-studio, firebase, login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] problema al implementar el FirebaseAuthListener alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` es una interfaz por lo que tienes que proveerle una implementacion al momento de la inicializacion.

Cambia:

```
FirebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener();
```

Por:

```
FirebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
  @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Y el segundo error te esta diciendo que el recurso `R.id.Contraseña` es un `TextView` en el XML pero estas intentando convertirlo a `EditText`, algo que sera imposible. Ve a tu XML y cambialo por un `<EditText />`.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo Einer me sirvió mucho tu aporte saludos

Comment: @CHELUY por favor marca la pregunta como respondida.